What was different in 1948 regarding the status of Urdu?
In 1948, Pakistan's founder Muhammad Ali Jinnah visited Dhaka and declared that Urdu would be the only state language of Pakistan.
In present-day Pakistan, there are between 74 and 78 regional languages. Urdu remains the state language, and Pakistani students are required to study it as a separate subject until the 12th grade. However, regional languages are used for education, except at the higher education level. Government recruitment exams, such as those for the civil service and military, are conducted in English.
In present-day Pakistan, Urdu is the national language and has been designated to be used for official purposes. The Supreme Court has ordered the adoption of Urdu as the official language for government documents, indicating a move away from English, which has been the co-official language at the federal level. However, the use of English is still prevalent until Urdu fully replaces it for official use.
At the provincial level, each province in Pakistan has the autonomy to use its regional languages for official matters alongside Urdu. Therefore, while Urdu is promoted for national unity and federal communication, provinces may use regional languages such as Sindhi, Punjabi, Pashto, and others depending on the province.
What was different in 1948 regarding the status of Urdu?

Was Urdu declared as a sole medium for everything from primary education to secondary education, government documentation, and government correspondence, thereby totally ignoring the existence of Bengali as a federal as well as provincial language?

If so, what was the decision regarding the other dominant regional languages (e.g., Punjabi, Sindhi, Balochi, Pashto, etc.) of West Pakistan?
Please supply adequate reference to back your answer.

There are issues with the Wikipedia article:

However, the Pakistan Public Service Commission removed Bengali from the list of approved subjects, as well as from currency notes and stamps. The central education minister Fazlur Rahman made extensive preparations to make Urdu the only state language of the Dominion of Pakistan.[19]

This quote is taken from Al Helal, B (2003). Bhasha Andoloner Itihas (History of the Language Movement) (in Bengali). Agamee Prakashani, Dhaka. ISBN 984-401-523-5. This writer is not a researcher; he is a novelist. Secondly, this book was first published in 2003.
The primary sources of the history of the language movement in East Bengal are considered two or three books of prof. Badruddin Umar. His books are not referenced in the above context.

Related: Why did the the East-Pakistanis oppose Urdu as their national language while Indians accepted Hindi as theirs?


@user366312 You removed that phrase but we still don't know what question of historical fact you're asking us to answer. Is there something specific not addressed here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengali_language_movement

This article looks very relevant if you can track down a copy. Even the one page preview is helpful: https://www.proquest.com/openview/3e4f1a19f44bf0ff4856d6e6022a1cf3/1

I suspect that muse is also relevant
